# how to save home address programmatically in iphone addressbook?

Tags: iphone, abaddressbook

how to save home address "add new address" in iphone addressbook by programming, not interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to an ABAddressBookRef. Read the following documentation, it shows you exactly how to do what you want: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/BasicObjects.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH3-SW1

Comment: I don't understand, can U sent me simple code only for address, i can do name, email, phone number, but address I need

Answer (score 1):

Have you read [this section of the Address Book Framework Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/DirectInteraction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH6-SW1)?